# Is there a better variant of the Auxiliary Angle Method?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently learning the Auxiliary Angle Method. Is either the sine or cosine variant of the method preferable?

$R*\sin(\theta±\alpha)$

$R*\cos(\theta±\alpha)$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](https://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php) may be of some help.

The only difference is that for $R \cdot \sin (\theta \pm \alpha)$, where $R = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$, we would use $\alpha = \arctan \dfrac {b}{a},$ while with $R \cdot \cos (\theta \pm \alpha)$, we would use $\alpha = \arctan \dfrac {a}{b}$.